# jQuery sliding of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So, my code is supposed to move the pink coloured div to position 'right : 10px;' yet it is not working. here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MHSL2/) for it. All replies will be appreciated.

HTML:
    
    About

```
<div id="aboutSector"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
function aboutShow() {
$("#aboutSector").animate({ right: "10px" }, "fast");
};
```

CSS:

```
#navBar {
width: 80%;
height: 40px;
left: 10%;
top: 0px;
position: absolute;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px black;
}
```

Comment: Working fine!! http://jsfiddle.net/kesamkiran/MHSL2/1/

Comment: the point is that we dont have to follow the link just to view the code

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include jquery. You really should post code and a fiddle together

Comment: I'm really stupid. I forgot to add the link to the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has obtrusive java script in it.  Instead of having an `onclick` event, I put an event listener on it.  You're fiddle also didn't have jQuery on it, so I've added that in my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/MHSL2/5/).

**The HTML**

```
<div id="navBar">
    <button id="aboutButton">About</button>
</div>
<div id="aboutSector"></div>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aboutButton").click(function() {
    $("#aboutSector").animate({ right: "10px" }, "fast");
  });
});
```

You had an an `undefined` error in your original code.  If you wanted to get fancy, you can slide it back after the next click.

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aboutButton").click(function() {
      var right = $("#aboutSector").css("right"), 
          shifter = (right == "10px") ? "0px" : "10px"; 

      $("#aboutSector").animate({ right: shifter }, "fast");
    });
});
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/MHSL2/8/).